# Is this correct params passing in vue router 4?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-router4

I want to pass data through vue router 4.
Here is my code: `this.$router.push({ path: "/clients", params: { tabValue: 'legalEntities' } });`

I do this on my submit button, and when I'm open to other component I want to check is there params in route, on this way:

```
    getTabValue() {
            if (this.$route.params.tabValue) {
                this.tab = this.$route.params.tabValue;
            }
            else {
                this.tab = 'persons';
            }
        }
```

I hope anyone can say why this is not working, if it's matters I use created() lifecycle hook on loading route data.

EDIT:

`/client` route declaration

```
{
    path: "/clients",
    name: "Clients",
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "clients" */'@/components/Clients/Clients'),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
    },
  },
```

Comment: How do you declare your `/clients` route?

Comment: I added that to post, so you can check

Answer (score 0):

I think you confused path params with query params.

For example in `/users/123?tab=info` 123 (user id) is a path parameter, while `tab=info` is a query parameter.

#### If you want a path parameter: `/clients/persons`

In Vue Router, you can describe a path parameter in the route by prefixing it with a colon:

```
{
  path: "/clients/:tab",
  name: "Clients",
}
```

Then you would be able to use it like that:

```
// while navigating
router.push({ name: 'Clients', params: { tab: 'persons' })

// on the page
route.params.tab
```

#### If you want a query parameter: `/clients?tab=persons`

You can simply use `query` attribute of a route:

```
// while navigating
router.push({ name: 'Clients', query: { tab: 'persons' })

// on the page
route.query.tab
```

Comment: But then I set `console.log(this.$route.params.tab);` in `mounted()` I get undefined